# What 'T' and 'Z' means in date

Tags: time

I need some information about this date '2015-05-12T00:00:00Z'. What does it mean 'T' and 'Z'? Anyone can help me?I don't know how they mean. I need to convert this data in another format

Answer (score 106, accepted):

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines formats for representing date-time values as text.

- The `T` is just a marker for where the time part begins.
- The `Z` is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, meaning [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hour-minutes-seconds). Pronounced “Zulu” per military and aviation tradition.

From the Wikipedia article on [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete date expression, the letter `T` as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example "2007-04-05T14:30".
>
> [...]
>
> If the time is in UTC, add a `Z` directly after the time without a space. `Z` is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".