# ISO 8601 and [T], [Z] characters

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso

Is it correct, that [T] and [Z] both characters indicate about UTC time format.

Furthermore [T] just split **date** and **time** parts?

```js
var dates = [
  '2016-05-03',         // date only: UTC
  '2016-05-03Z',        // Z character: UTC
  '2016-05-03 00:00',   // exist time, missing T & Z: local
  '2016-05-03 00:00Z',  // exist Z: UTC
  '2016-05-03T00:00',   // exist T: UTC
  '2016-05-03T00:00Z'   // exist Z, T: UTC
];

dates.map(function(d) {  
  document.writeln(d + ':' + Date.parse(d) + '<br />');
});
```

Comment: For anyone else also reading up on these 2 characters, [here's another really good answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209941/what-t-and-z-means-in-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right:

> The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time,

And the Z means "Zulu time" (UTC). [From that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405125/405623).

More on **T** and **Z** in [wikipedia article on ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a
>   space.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO 8601 date and time format is intended to be both human and machine readable. In Structured Query Language (SQL), the standardized programming language that is used for all standard computer databases, the ISO 8601 date and time format in SQL is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", always without the "T" preceding the time.

Here is the actual ISO 8601 date and time format specification:
https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Here is the date and time format in SQL:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp