# Different dates on safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

Given a date in string format I am trying to get the same result in both browsers safari and chrome, with not success. I know that is a lot post about this but I don't get a clear answer for this

I'm using this code

```js
new Date("2019-02-21 13:25".replace(/\s/, 'T'))
```

result for Chrome

> Thu Feb 21 2019 13:25:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) (correct one)

result for Safari

> Thu Feb 21 2019 08:25:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

And when I use this other option

```js
new Date("2019-02-21 13:25".replace(/\s/, 'T')+'Z')
```

result for Chrome

> Thu Feb 21 2019 08:25:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) (wrong)

result for Safari

> Thu Feb 21 2019 08:25:00 GMT-0500 (EST)(wrong)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What 'T' and 'Z' means in date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209941/what-t-and-z-means-in-date)

Comment: Is not the same question @Sam

Comment: What is wrong exactly in the second part?

Comment: @amd it should be this Thu Feb 21 2019 13:25:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: Not correct, `2019-02-21T13:25Z` means 13:25 in UTC which is 8:25 in UTC -5

Comment: What should I do then to get the expected result?

Comment: Edit your post and ask the correct question, so you get better results,
You are asking 1) about the difference in implementation, 2) how to parse a date in the local timezone (I think this what you want)

Answer (score 1):

The only guaranteed format in JavaScript is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` as per the ECMA specs. other formats are browser dependent.

so passing `2019-02-21T13:25Z` will work as expected in all browsers. (note the T and the Z at the end)

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format

From the ECMA specs:

> ##### 21.4.1.18 Date Time String Format
>
> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`
>
> Where the elements are as follows:
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | `YYYY` | is the year in the proleptic Gregorian calendar as four decimal digits from 0000 to 9999, or as an [expanded year](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-expanded-years) of "+" or "-" followed by six decimal digits. |
> | `-` | "-" (hyphen) appears literally twice in the string. |
> | `MM` | is the month of the year as two decimal digits from 01 (January) to 12 (December). |
> | `DD` | is the day of the month as two decimal digits from 01 to 31. |
> | `T` | "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element. |
> | `HH` | is the number of complete hours that have passed since midnight as two decimal digits from 00 to 24. |
> | `:` | ":" (colon) appears literally twice in the string. |
> | `mm` | is the number of complete minutes since the start of the hour as two decimal digits from 00 to 59. |
> | `ss` | is the number of complete seconds since the start of the minute as two decimal digits from 00 to 59. |
> | `.` | "." (dot) appears literally in the string. |
> | `sss` | is the number of complete milliseconds since the start of the second as three decimal digits. |
> | `Z` | is the UTC offset representation specified as "Z" (for UTC with no offset) or as either "+" or "-" followed by a time expression `HH:mm` (a subset of the [time zone offset string format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-time-zone-offset-strings) for indicating local time ahead of or behind UTC, respectively) |

Comment: It works but is returning the wrong result, check again the question

Comment: I didn't say it will not work, but it's not guaranteed to work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with a progressive app where it works perfect for android not in iOS. I found the issue with Safari. And To get the same result I have found the issue and fixed it.

In safari It needs the date formatted like this **yyyy/mm/dd not yyyy-mm-dd**. So replacing the date format I get the same result for both chrome and safari.

You don't need to replace the space with Z or add T in the end. It just fixes the invalid date issue but does not show same result like in chrome.

```
var test = new Date('2019-11-15 23:43:22'); // Invalid Date
alert(test);

var testTwo = new Date('2019-11-15 23:43:22'.replace(/-/g, '/')); // works same as chrome
alert(testTwo);
```

**Fri Nov 15 2019 23:43:22 GMT+0530 (IST)**

I am still not much aware **Date** in Safari, But this works like charm for me.